# Decrypt an encrypted string in Databricks using GCM mode

Tags: azure, apache-spark, encryption, databricks, aes-gcm

I'm trying to decrypt a string in databricks using `aes_decrypt` function with GCM mode. But, it doesn't seem to work with IV. Didn't find any details about how to use IV with `aes_decrypt` function : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/functions/aes_decrypt?source=recommendations

Here are the details of the string, key & IV:

```
IV: udukduo07ffu2shi
Key: 3uboo7wshaphu69e
Encrypted String: pJvnV+03zyM+FMOMQqFCXWdeucmoPfgApbmp5l4SsdxUHCJw4IuWUQnd
```

I tried running this in databricks:

```
%sql
SELECT cast(aes_decrypt(unbase64('pJvnV+03zyM+FMOMQqFCXWdeucmoPfgApbmp5l4SsdxUHCJw4IuWUQnd'), '3uboo7wshaphu69e', 'GCM') AS STRING);
```

It's giving me this error :

> org.apache.spark.SparkRuntimeException: [INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE] The value of parameter(s) 'expr, key' in `aes_encrypt`/`aes_decrypt` is invalid: Detail message: Tag mismatch!

Any help with this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [linked GCM example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/functions/aes_decrypt?source=recommendations#examples) requires as first parameter the concatenation of IV, ciphertext and tag, where the IV must be 12 bytes long and the tag 16 bytes.

This can be easily verified with CyberChef:

```
Data (Base64):      2sXi+jZd/ws+qFC1Tnzvvde5lz+8Haryz9HHBiyrVohXUG7LHA==
Data (hex):         dac5e2fa365dff0b3ea850b54e7cefbdd7b9973fbc1daaf2cfd1c7062cab568857506ecb1c
12 bytes IV (hex):  dac5e2fa365dff0b3ea850b5
Ciphertext (hex):                           4e7cefbdd7b9973fbc
16 bytes tag (hex):                                           1daaf2cfd1c7062cab568857506ecb1c
```

which can be successfully decrypted to *Spark SQL* using AES GCM, s. [CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=AES_Decrypt(%7B%27option%27:%27UTF8%27,%27string%27:%271234567890abcdef%27%7D,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27dac5e2fa365dff0b3ea850b5%27%7D,%27GCM%27,%27Hex%27,%27Raw%27,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%271daaf2cfd1c7062cab568857506ecb1c%27%7D,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D)&input=NGU3Y2VmYmRkN2I5OTczZmJj).

---

The example you posted uses a 16 bytes IV. `Encrypted String` contains the concatenation of ciphertext and 16 bytes tag:

```
12 bytes IV (ASCII): udukduo07ffu2shi
Enc. Str. (Base64):  pJvnV+03zyM+FMOMQqFCXWdeucmoPfgApbmp5l4SsdxUHCJw4IuWUQnd
Enc. Str. (hex):     a49be757ed37cf233e14c38c42a1425d675eb9c9a83df800a5b9a9e65e12b1dc541c2270e08b965109dd
Ciphertext (hex):    a49be757ed37cf233e14c38c42a1425d675eb9c9a83df800a5b9
16 bytes tag (hex):                                                      a9e65e12b1dc541c2270e08b965109dd
```

which can be successfully decrypted with AES GCM to *this is the plaintext data*, s. [CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=AES_Decrypt(%7B%27option%27:%27UTF8%27,%27string%27:%273uboo7wshaphu69e%27%7D,%7B%27option%27:%27UTF8%27,%27string%27:%27udukduo07ffu2shi%27%7D,%27GCM%27,%27Hex%27,%27Raw%27,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27a9e65e12b1dc541c2270e08b965109dd%27%7D,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D)&input=YTQ5YmU3NTdlZDM3Y2YyMzNlMTRjMzhjNDJhMTQyNWQ2NzVlYjljOWE4M2RmODAwYTViOQ).

---

Bottom Line:

The Databricks implementation and the example you posted use different IV sizes. Although GCM can handle any IV size, the recommended IV size is 12 bytes, which should be used for performance and compatibility reasons, and is commonly applied by default. The most secure and default tag size is 16 bytes.

`aes_decrypt()` does not allow the specification of IV and tag size, i.e. IV and tag are separated using the standard sizes. So unless the values can be configured somewhere else, only AES GCM encryptions using a 12 bytes IV and a 16 bytes tag can be decrypted by the Databricks implementation.

This means that in order for your AES-GCM encrytions to be decrypted with the Databricks implementation, the standard sizes for IV and tag, as well as the format of the Databricks implementation, must be applied:
`IV (12 bytes)|ciphertext|tag (16 bytes)`.